# Java 8 streams - modifying all elements in a group

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a collection of objects of Class A

```
class A {
    String code;
    long timestamp;
    long largestTimestamp;
}
```

I have to populate the largestTimestamp field for each object (the largest "timestamp" value in the group of objects with the same code). I can do this in two steps as follows -

```
Map<String, Long> largestTimestampMap = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getCode, A::getTimestamp, Long::max));
list.forEach(a -> a.setLargestTimestamp(largestTimestampMap.get(a.getCode())));
```

Is there a way to combine these into a single stream chain?

Comment: instead `list.forEach(...)` you can use this `list.replaceAll(a -> {a.setLargestTimestamp(largestTimestampMap.get(a.getCode()));return a;});
` also.

Comment: As shown in the answers: There **is** a way to combine them. And as obvious from the answers: You should **not** do this. These are two different steps. Keep them separate for maintainability and readability. Signed: *The Programmer Who Will Have To Maintain Your Code In The Future*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can combine them into a single *pipeline* as follows:

```
list.stream()
     .map(a -> new A(a.getCode(), a.getTimestamp(),
                list.stream()
                    .filter(b -> a.getCode().equals(b.getCode()))
                    .mapToLong(A::getTimestamp)
                    .max().getAsLong()))           
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or if you want to avoid creating a new list but instead modify the existing one like in your example then use `replaceAll`:

```
list.replaceAll(a -> new A(a.getCode(), a.getTimestamp(),
                        list.stream()
                                .filter(b -> a.getCode().equals(b.getCode()))
                                .mapToLong(A::getTimestamp)
                                .max().getAsLong()));
```

However, I'd recommend avoiding this approach:

1) because it has worse performance than your current implementation, this solution requires iterating over `list` again `forEach` element in it. Whereas the Map approach you've shown only requires a single `get` call and we all know how fast looking up in a map is.

2) There's more code.

Yes, you can refactor the code inside the `map` intermediate operation into a method to make it look shorter but ultimately it's still longer.

*Sometimes the best approach requires two or more separate lines and in this case, it's best to proceed with your approach.*

Comment: Isn't better in `replaceAll` solution just use `setLargestTimestamp(...)` instead create _new_ object? `list.replaceAll(a -> {a.setLargestTimestamp(largestTimestampMap.get(a.getCode()));return a;});`

Comment: @HadiJ if one is going to be using `largestTimestampMap.get(a.getCode())` then I'd stick with `forEach` i.e. `list.forEach(a -> a.setLargestTimestamp(largestTimestampMap.get(a.getCode())));` as the OP is doing simply because it's more idiomatic and intuitive. if one is going to b using the `replaceAll` solution i mentioned above (which I've recommended not to) then yes you could use a `replaceAll` with a lambda statement block setting the properties of the objects in place and then returning it whch means one is not necessarily required to create new `A` objects as shown above. btw good shout!

Answer (score 3):

You might just be looking for (if *populate the largestTimestamp field for each object* means saving the same `largestTimeStamp` for the entire list) :

```
// find the largest timestamp
long largestTimeStamp = list.stream()
        .mapToLong(A::getTimestamp)
        .max()
        .orElse(Long.MIN_VALUE);

// iterate through the list to set its value
list.forEach(a -> a.setLargestTimestamp(largestTimeStamp));
```

---

If bound to do this under a single line of code, you can use (edited to align with the existing code as clarified by Aomine in comments) :

```
List<A> output = list.stream()
        .map(a -> new A(a.getCode(), a.getTimestamp(),
                list.stream().filter(b -> a.getCode().equals(b.getCode()))
                        .mapToLong(A::getTimestamp).max().orElse(a.getTimestamp())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: close but not quite. this gets the `largestTimeStamp` and sets "every" other elements timestamp to that which is not what the original code is doing. the original code is getting the largest timestamp for a given `getCode` and sets this specific object to the value retrieved. [see my stream approach for clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53567561/java-8-streams-modifying-all-elements-in-a-group/53569057#53569057)

Comment: @Aomine I get it what you are saying now... in the question *populate the largestTimestamp field for each object* , I inferred it as setting the same value for all objects, while the code does keep the max for objects with same code in the list.. indeed a filter would be required there.

Answer (score 0):

Just a different thought, but can't you structure your class A like as shown below

```
class A {
  String code;
  long timeStamp;
  TimeStampWrapper timeStampWrapper;
}

class TimeStampWrapper {
  long maxTimeStamp;
  long minTimeStamp;
  ...
}
```

With this approach you will only need 1 stream traversal and just a single set operation to set maxTimeStamp, minTimeStamp, etc etc.